# Python: Find max value from set neighbourhood of a point that is closest to a point from another dataset, the first df is very large

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` has two columns. I'd like to find the index `idx` of `row` from `df1`, that contains in `col1` the minimum distance from the value of `df2 col1`.

Next, I want to find the max value of `df1 col2` from `neighborhood [idx-10, idx+10]`. Then attach that value to `df2` to corresponding row for which the min distance was found.

Here is an example of the two columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1.5,2.5,3,3.5,3.95,4.55],
                    "B": [0.25, 0.6, 1.34, 0.75, 0.16, 1.04, 0.99]})
      A     B
0  1.00  0.25
1  1.50  0.60
2  2.50  1.34
3  3.00  0.75
4  3.50  0.16
5  3.95  1.04
6  4.55  0.99


 df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A1": [1.06,2.34, 3.70],
                     "C": ["pink", "blue", "orange"]})  

  A1       C
0  1.06    pink
1  2.34    blue
2  3.70  orange
```

Here is the desired result:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"A1":[1.06,2.34, 3.70],
                    "B": [0.25, 0.6, 1.04],
                    "C": ["pink", "blue", "orange"] })


  A1     B       C
0  1.06  0.25    pink
1  2.34  0.60    blue
2  3.70  1.04  orange
```

I know that I could merge these data frames, but the problem is that one of them, `df1`, is very large, so it would take ridiculous amount of memory to compute all possible distances of columns `A` and `A1`. So, maybe there is something more efficient than that?
I know that this example is not exact, because the column `B` of the resulting data frame consists of values that exactly match the row of `A` where
`A[i]-A1[j] = min|A[i]-A1[j]|`,

whereas I need the B value to be the maximum of B from rows where A = `[A[i]-5, A[i]+5]`.

Comment: shouldn't your get 0.16 for orange in df3? 3.70 is closer to 3.50 than 3.95.

Answer (score 0):

The logic for the provided output is the fully clear,but if you want to merge on the closest value in A/A1, use `pandas.merge_asof`:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1.rename(columns={'A': 'A1'}),
                    on='A1', direction='nearest')
```

the condition on `idx±10` is also unclear, but if you want to set a maximum distance use `tolerance=10`

output:

```
     A1       C     B
0  1.06    pink  0.25
1  2.34    blue  1.34
2  3.70  orange  0.16
```

Comment: No, I'd like to find the maximum of B in the range of [A[i]-10;A[i]+10], but set the value next to the row for which [A[i]-A1[j]] = min.